# How to have nested ngfor with dynamic calls to api

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an array of object that I get back at once from my API and I display them in `.component.html` like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of ObjectArray">
    <div>{{obj.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I need to make second call to API with each one of the objects where I will populate second object array and will need to display it underneath `obj.name` and I tried to do that like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of ObjectArray">
    <div data-dummy="{{populateAnotherObjectArray(obj.id)}}"></div>
    <div>{{obj.name}}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let anotherObj of AnotherObjArray">
        {{anotherObj.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

`populateAnotherObjectArray(obj.id)` is a function in `component.ts` file where I populate AnotherObjArray.

Now I only get endless calls to second API.

I tried to user Directive and EventEmitter but I don't get anything there.

Is there a simple way to do this?

**Update:**

Lets say 1st call to API I get in `ObjectArray`:

```
[obj1From1stArray, obj2From1stArray]
```

now I call API again `this.api.populate2ndArray(obj1From1stArray.id)` and get in `AnotherObjecArray`:

```
[obj1From2ndArray]
```

and after that `this.api.populate2ndArray(obj2From1stArray.id)` and get in `AnotherObjecArray`:

```
[obj2From2ndArray]
```

What I get on my `.html` page with current answer:

```
obj1From1stArray name
    obj1From2ndArray
    obj2From2ndArray
obj2From1stArray name
    obj1From2ndArray
    obj2From2ndArray
```

What I want:

```
obj1From1stArray name 
    obj1From2ndArray
obj2From1stArray name
    obj2From2ndArray
```

Comment: can you add the component code as well  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid calling functions inside directives and interpolations as much as possible. If you aren't controlling the change detection strategy, they will be called too many times. You could trigger the call in the controller before displaying the data. Try the following

Controller

```js
import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  this.apiService.getObjectArray().pipe(
    switchMap(arr1 => {
      this.ObjectArray = arr1;
      return forkJoin(arr1.map(item => this.apiService.getAnotherObjArray(item['id'])));
    }),
    catchError(err1 => {
      // handle error
      return of(err1);
    })
  ).subscribe(
    arr2 => {
      this.ObjectArray.forEach(obj, index => this.ObjectArray['AnotherObjArray'] = arr2[index]);
    },
    err2 => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<div *ngFor="let obj of ObjectArray">
  <div>{{obj.name}}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let anotherObj of obj.AnotherObjArray">
    {{anotherObj.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: although this does work, it is redundant because I could just call a separate method and populate the another array with simple `foreach`. What I get now is a 2D array That I now have map to coresponding `obj.name` which I can't do. This is why I need to populate `AnotherObjArray` right away like in my example. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to avoid subscribing in a `forEach` loop as well because there will be multiple subscriptions. Here there is one subscription that you have control over. If you were to show the structure of the objects, we could try to extend this solution to map to your preference.

Comment: I have updated the question with example what I want to achieve.

Comment: You could ignore the `AnotherObjArray` member variable and make it a property of the parent object. I've modified the code. See if it works for you.

Comment: This works! Thank you! I want to add that since subscription is controlled now I could also add a index and `slice` array to match to exact object but this is better solution.